# How to copy a function?

Tags: aliases

If I get the function definition with

```lisp
(setq wrapped-copy (symbol-function 'fn))
```

how can I make a copy such that I can redefine the same function with a wrapped version?
like

```lisp
(fset 'fn #'(lambda () (wrapped-copy)))
```

I tried with `copy-seq` but I think it copies by reference, so the anon function looses the function definition in the wrapped copy

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "redefine" and "wrapped version". `fset` lets you define an alias, like `defalias` does. And you're using a variable whose value is a function in function position. Elisp is a Lisp 2, not a Lisp 1, so you would need `(lambda () (funcall wrapped-copy))`. But as I say, to me it's not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`funcall` or `apply`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Calling-Functions.html#Calling-Functions):

```el
(setq wrapped-copy (symbol-function 'emacs-version))
(fset 'fn (lambda () (funcall wrapped-copy)))

(fn)
"GNU Emacs 28.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.32, cairo version 1.16.0)
 of 2020-06-15"
```

Although, in general, I would use an [advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html#Advising-Functions) for wrapping a function.