# How to create an independent copy of a function's definition?

Tags: functions, advice, aliases, isearch-filter-predicate, symbol-function

I want to create a modified *copy* of `re-search-forward` and advise this copy to be sensitive to `isearch-filter-predicate`. I tried:

```el
(defun make-search-sensitive-to-ifpmod-advice (orig-fun &rest args)
  "Temporary advice the search functions to make them sensitive to
`isearch-filter-predicate'"
  (let ((POINT (point)))
    (catch 'filtered
      (while (apply orig-fun args)
        (let ((B (match-beginning 0))
              (E (match-end 0)))
          ;; 1 - If all points in the region that matches the search
          ;; from the previous "search-command" meet the criteria
          ;; accepted by the filter, then the loop stops (`throw') and
          ;; returns the position `(point)`:
          (when (funcall isearch-filter-predicate B E)
            (throw 'filtered (point)))))
      ;; 2 - If the search is unsuccessful, or does not meet
      ;; the criteria accepted by the filter, then return to the
      ;; starting position and return the value `nil'.
      (goto-char POINT)
      nil)))
```

```el
(defalias 're-search-forward-ifpmod
  (symbol-function 're-search-forward)
  "Copy of `re-search-forward' function (to be) adviced to obey to
`isearch-filter-predicate'")
(defalias 'search-forward-regexp-ifpmod 're-search-forward-ifpmod)

(advice-add 're-search-forward-ifpmod
            :around
            #'make-search-sensitive-to-ifpmod-advice)
```

I tested this code and it works but it generates a strange bug:
https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=69573

[Eager macro-expansion failure: (wrong-type-argument integer-or-marker-p nil)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/80628/15606)

So my question is (regardless of the bug and the issue I mentioned above): Does the usage of `defalias` combined with `symbol-function` create an "independent" **copy** (not an **alias**) of the original function? If not, how to do that?

**Note added.** By "independent copy," I mean that a modification, such as an advice, to the original function should not affect the copy of that function. Let's take this code as an example:

```el
(defun test-origin ()
  "Test function"
  (message "origin"))

(defalias 'defalias-copy 'test-origin
  "Alias of `test-origin'")

(defalias 'symbol-function-copy
  (symbol-function 'test-origin)
  "Copy (in my intention) of `test-origin`")

(defun test-override ()
  (message "override"))
```

1. If I advice `test-origin`:

```el
(advice-add 'test-origin
            :override
            #'test-override)

(test-origin)             ; => "override"

(defalias-copy)           ; => "override"

(symbol-function-copy)    ; => "origin"
```

also `defalias-copy` get adviced. (This is not good if I want override `test-origin` with an adviced version of `defalias-copy` later.)

2. If I advice `defalias-copy`:

```el
(advice-remove 'test-origin #'test-override)

(advice-add 'defalias-copy
            :override
            #'test-override)


(test-origin)             ; => "origin"

(defalias-copy)           ; => "override"

(symbol-function-copy)    ; => "origin"
```

3. If I advice `symbol-function-copy`

```el
(advice-remove 'defalias-copy #'test-override)

(advice-add 'symbol-function-copy
            :override
            #'test-override)

(test-origin)             ; => "origin"

(defalias-copy)           ; => "origin"

(symbol-function-copy)    ; => "override"
```

But due to the bug mentioned above, I suspect that the combination of `defalias` and `symbol-function` is not the appropriate way to obtain a copy of a function that is completely independent from the original

- I thought of using `symbol-function` based on this: [How to copy a function?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/63118/15606).
- My purpose is to advice (override) a function with an adviced copy of the same function.

Comment: Please summarize the problem (bug or whatever) with your code. To understand the question readers shouldn't need to follow links.

Comment: @Drew I'm not asking about the problem. I'm just asking if my code creates a copy of `re-search-forward`. The links are there just to justify my question.

Comment: @Drew I clarified this point in my question (I hope..).

Answer (score 0):

No. Nothing about `defalias` or `symbol-function` makes a copy of the function.

Comment: Thanks. So, why do the original function and its copy behave differently? And how can I create (if possible) a copy of a function? (Do I need to open another issue or can I edit the current one?)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. I think it does what you're looking for.

```lisp
(defalias 'bar 'forward-char)
(advice-add 'bar :after (lambda (&rest _) (message "AFTER")))
```

```
M-x forward-char ; No message "AFTER"
M-x bar          ; Message "AFTER"
```

```lisp
(symbol-function 'forward-char) ; => #<subr forward-char>
(symbol-function 'bar) ; => forward-char
```

IOW, you advise `bar`, not the original function, `forward-char`. And you defalias `bar` to `forward-char`, **not** to `(symbol-function 'forward-char)`.

Note this difference:

```lisp
(defalias 'foo (symbol-function 'forward-char))
(eq (symbol-function 'foo) (symbol-function 'forward-char)) ; => t

(defalias 'bar 'forward-char)
(eq (symbol-function 'bar) (symbol-function 'forward-char)) ; => nil
```

Comment: This is not what I asked for. I need a copy of the original function that is **completely independent** from it. In my tests, if I advice the original function, its alias will also be adviced. I went to `symbol-function` because of this question https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/63118/15606. The point is that I want to override a function with and adviced copy of the same function. I tried and I get this error: apply: Lisp nesting exceeds ‘max-lisp-eval-depth’

Comment: I edited my question to better explain my purpose.

Comment: I'm really sorry. But I don't think that I'm evolved or changed my question. I probably didn't explain myself well, so I just tried to further clarify my intention. However, I had already expressed at the beginning that I needed to obtain a copy **completely independent** from the original function and that a pure `defalias` was not suitable. I have great respect for the time you dedicate to helping users who are not very experienced like me, and I apologize again for the misunderstanding.

Comment: I checked and this sentence was already present in the first version of my question: *So my question is: Is it correct the use of defalias combined with symbol-function to create an "independent" COPY (not an ALIAS) of the original function?*. My fault, I thought I had explained myself well.